# PHP and redirection

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I am fairly new to this site and have a question about a problem that I have recently.
How to interact with a page on which we just made a redirection?
That is, after validating a form, I would like to be able to redirect the user to the login page and show him a success message such as: Successful registration! But I can not do it.

Comment: Sorry, Hello everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but it will work.

The [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) can be used to redirect a user to a page.

`header("Location: myFile.php?message=success"); // success can be changed to fail`

You can then use this code on the destination page to display the message accordingly.

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])) {

    if($_GET['message'] == 'success') {
        echo 'Registered successfully!';
    } elseif($_GET['message'] == 'fail') {
        echo 'Registration failed.';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a redirect use the `header()` function:

```
header("Location: [you-url]");
```

To show a message I suggest you use `$_SESSION[]` or `$_GET[]` both of these variables are superglobal variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Also remember if you use `$_SESSION[]` then you have to put `session_start()` at the beginning of each page...

**TRY THIS (`$_SESSION[]`session solution):**

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Successful Registration";
header("Location: [redirect-url]");
```

**On the display page:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
}

?>
```

**TRY THIS (`$_GET[]` solution):**

```
header("Location: [redirect-url]?message=Successful%20Registration");
```

**On the display page:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
    echo $_GET['message'];
}

?>
```

You can change these up depending on if it failed or not!

Comment: Your `$_GET` solution won't work since you have a space in the parameter. You should change the space to `%20`.

Comment: @rpm192 Usually it auto adds it but I changed it anyway

Comment: You added it to the `$_SESSION` one, I was talking about the `$_GET` one.

Comment: @rpm192 my bad!

Answer (score -1):

I'd use $_SESSION variables to store the message you wish to display.
Echo the contents of this $_SESSION variable when you want to show it and then UNSET() the variable once you're done